# Exclude a certain row

Tags: mysql, select

I have a query with several joins.
My query returns the top ten people for a leader-board based on their total steps.
I want to exclude all rows that have a value in the `privacy` column set to `out`.

MySQL query as it stands:

```
SELECT ga.owner_id, u.displayname, g.title, SUM(ga.steps) as `Total Steps`, u.user_id, g.group_id, pri.privacy FROM engine4_passport_goalactivitys ga
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_goals goals ON goals.goal_id = ga.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_passports p ON p.passport_id = goals.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_users u ON u.user_id = p.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_teams t ON t.owner_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_group_groups g ON g.group_id = t.group_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_privacy pri on pri.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY `Total Steps` DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT ga.owner_id, u.displayname, g.title, SUM(ga.steps) as `Total Steps`, u.user_id, g.group_id, pri.privacy FROM engine4_passport_goalactivitys ga
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_goals goals ON goals.goal_id = ga.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_passports p ON p.passport_id = goals.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_users u ON u.user_id = p.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_teams t ON t.owner_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_group_groups g ON g.group_id = t.group_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_privacy pri on pri.user_id = u.user_id
AND pri.privacy <> 'out'
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY `Total Steps` DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

The difference between the two queries above is the line:

`AND pri.privacy <> 'out'`

however, instead of excluding users with privacy set to 'out' it includes them in the query and just sets their privacy value to `null`

I have also tried `where` instead of `and` but it just returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it in WHERE clause instead of AND

```
where pri.privacy <> 'out'
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED -

```
SELECT ga.owner_id, u.displayname, g.title, SUM(ga.steps) as `Total Steps`, u.user_id, g.group_id, pri.privacy FROM engine4_passport_goalactivitys ga
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_goals goals ON goals.goal_id = ga.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_passports p ON p.passport_id = goals.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_users u ON u.user_id = p.owner_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_teams t ON t.owner_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_group_groups g ON g.group_id = t.group_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_passport_privacy pri on pri.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE pri.privacy is null OR pri.privacy = 'in'
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY `Total Steps` DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```